# Reflecting curves over $y=x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm struggling to reflect curves over the line of $ y = x $, I have no trouble reflecting shapes over the x or y axis, but always struggle when it comes to $ y = x$. I always have to resort to plotting which takes up a lot of time.

Could someone give me any advice on how to reflect curves over the line $y=x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Reflections about the line $y = x$ is accomplished by interchanging the $x$ and the $y$ coordinates. Thus for $y = f(x)$, the reflection about the line $y = x$ is accomplished by $x = f(y)$.

For example, the reflection about the line $y = x$ for $y = x^2$ is the equation $x = y^2$. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the curve is complicated, you can just take particular, interesting points and switch the coordinates.  Every $x$-intercept becomes a $y$ intercept and vv., for instance.  Max's, min's, cusps, asymptotes and other features can be similarly transposed.  Then connect the dots appropriately.